# How can I automatically log in a user right after they register in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp framework to build my application. I want that, whenever a user registers he is automatically logged in and shown a particular page. Please tell me how do I achieve this functionality?
using xampp, with php 5.2 and mysql 5.0 on winXP.

Comment: +1 The question IS a bit vague, but definitely not negative territory, at least to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it comes down to the following:

- When your user is registered, store his login credentials
- Call $this->Auth->login()
- Redirect to your page

See more info about Auth::login() here:

http://api.cakephp.org/class/auth-component#method-AuthComponentlogin